# node_modules error on npx create-next-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I want to create a simple Next.js project, as I have done many times before. I ran `npx create-next-app <app name>`, `cd <app name>` and ran `npm run dev`. I am getting this error, and I cannot resolve it. I globally uninstalled and installed Node. I even tried `npm ci`—same error.

[image]

Comment: It says, that one of your modules is not found. Did you tried `npm i postcss`?

Comment: @Yoskutik Yes, I did. I also did an uninstall and installed it again. But nothing has changed. Still getting the same error.